# LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD in Soong?

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I have a makefile which uses LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD and I need to switch to Soong build system but I could not find how do I implement this command in Soong. More or less I need to copy the file after install step. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: I found cc_genrule but do not understand how it is invoked and is it possible at all to use in my case.

Comment: The main question is - what is this file and where do you want to copy it. For example, you can use ```prebuilt_etc``` to put your file in ```/system/etc/``` or ```/vendor/etc/ ```.

Comment: this is Bootanimation binary. I use customized clone of it which is put to vendor and overrides the original module. So in fact I want to copy "mybootanimation" to "bootanimation", in `system/bin`

Comment: I guess you need to use ```cc_prebuilt_binary``` in this case.

Comment: Checked docs, worth trying. Except that I do not see again how would i change the binary name during install :/

Comment: What about the ```stem``` property discussed in your previous post?

Comment: According to docs stem is not available to cc_prebuild_binary

Comment: Also by cc_prebuild_binary - how do I specify input and output? Looks like there is no output configuration at all and if I use just name of module as source I get "module source path .. does not exist".

Comment: But I see, that it is available: https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6186764/linux/latest/raw/cc.html#cc_prebuilt_binary

Comment: Thanks. So even with using stem, unfortunately i get the same "does not exist" message. So I still do not get how Soong works - is that because source binary is not built yet or I am not properly specifying src path.

Comment: Looks to me that cc_prebuilt_binary _implies_ that source file is in src folder (not out) and this is not the case

Comment: You can always look how it is already done in AOSP, try to grep all Android.bp files. e.g. ```grep -irn cc_prebuilt_binary --include=Android.bp```

Comment: If I understood correctly you need to specify ```srcs``` out you folder, if yes - you can link them to folder near your ```Android.bp```, because SOONG doesn't allow to work with files from the outside.